# Add content-type headers to each part of a multi-part form request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data, jquery-file-upload

Does anyone know how to add headers to each part of a multipart form request using javascript (jQuery or jQuery.fileupload plugin).

For instance, I'm uploading a image file and then additional form data in a `multipart/form-data` request.  The new server endpoint I have to use is now requiring the `Content-Type` header be set for each part of the multipart form.

The jquery.fileupload plugin handles this fine for the file upload part where it sets `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="<sourceFileName>"` and `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` for me fine automatically.  However I need to also specify `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` for the extra form data fields I am sending across and I cant seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can read [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/2918/how-to-set-a-request-header-in-a-jquery-ajax-call.aspx), but I don't know how to use it with jQuery-file-upload plugin.

Comment: Thanks but its not the request headers.  I can set the full request headers fine.  Like my question specifies, this is about the specific headers for the different parts of multipart request, not the request headers as a whole.